# Как сравнить значение из input через Fuzzywuzzy?

Tags: python, input, сравнение

Хотел сделать так, чтобы бот отвечал также на вопрос с одним смыслом "Какой сегодня день?". Когда начал проверять бот отвечал на любую бессвязную чушь одними и теми же ответами в том порядке, в котором они стоят в коде

```
import os
from datetime import date, time
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

name = input("Введите ваше имя: ")
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
clear()
print("Здравствуйте, " + name + "!" + " Вас приветствует бот Иларион, чем могу быть полезен?")
print("=======================================================================")
msg = input("Пишите тут: ") 
    
def new_func():
    msg = input("Пишите тут: ")
    return msg

if (msg == "Пинг", fuzz.ratio(msg, 'Пинг') > 75) or (msg == "Ping", fuzz.ratio(msg, 'Ping') > 25):
 pong = "Понг"
 print(pong)

 msg = new_func()

if (msg == "Какой сегодня день", fuzz.ratio(msg, 'Какой сегодня день?') > 25):
    print(date.today())

    msg = input("Пишите тут: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (msg == "Пинг", fuzz.ratio(msg, 'Пинг') > 75) or (msg == "Ping", fuzz.ratio(msg, 'Ping') > 25):
```

Как-то вы очень странно сравниваете. Фактически, вы пишете такие условия:

```
if кортеж(условие, условие) or кортеж(условие, условие):
```

При этом, булево значение любого вида коллекций считается истинным, если коллекция не пуста. Таким образом, ваши условия всегда выполняются, потому что у вас не пустые кортежи, в них по два элемента.

Даже если абсолютно все условия в скобках будут ложными, `if` всё-равно сработает. Проверим:

```
if (False,False) or (False,False):
    print('Сработало!')
```

Вывод:

```
Сработало!
```

Так что переписывайте ваши условия на нормальные логические операторы `and`, `or` и `not` вместо кортежей.